# Unable to write to output file error on windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I installed a windows server 2008 R2 and visual studio ultimate 2012 on a virtual server . I have a web application that used on an old server with .Net framework 3.5 and now I’m using the application with .Net framework 4.0 on IIS 7 and intranet on new server , everything is fine and clients uses the application with no problem .

But when I need to build the application by visual studio it sends these errors :

> 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3\vbc8DD4B87E37C7468C8D1466EA68743DC.TMP'
>   is corrupt    CVTRES : fatal

and

> Unable to write to output file
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\farasystem\1179059f\b8641c61\App_Theme_Default.s7yrhxe-.dll':
>   The specified image file did not contain a resource section.  vbc :

What I have tried so far :

1. reading many articles about errors
2. restarting visual studio
3. restating server
4. re-installing visual studio
5. changing temp folders address in environment variables tab
6. setting full control access for every temp folder and `IIS_USRS` and
   `Network Service` users
7. checking files for read-only attribute

But no luck.

Answer (score 1):

a Google search of "server 2008 default ACL permission C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"

returned a lot of promising how-tos including one from Microsoft Support entitled "Troubleshooting common permissions and security-related issues in ASP.NET" which is at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/910449

Try working through the steps there and let us know if you hit another snag.